# Weird dropdown behavior with tailwind and submenus

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Am using the tailwind grouping feature to create a dropdown with submenus that correspond to each link in it. It's working but the it seems to behave oddly as in the hover does not always stay. Any tips on getting it working more solidly? Here's my code and a link to the tailwind play. What happens is the main submenu sometimes disappears and doesn't always stay open when the "Dropdown" link is hovered on. Thanks

https://play.tailwindcss.com/OaMANUakh8

```
<li class="group relative flex bg-red-700">
  <a class="rounded-3xl px-1 py-0.5 text-lg hover:bg-[#3A4B66]" data-phx-id="m6-authenticated-nav-live"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down fa-2xs [li:hover>a>&amp;]:rotate-180 ml-0.5 transition" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dropdown</a>

  <ul class="absolute top-[48px] w-60 origin-top scale-0 transform rounded-xl bg-blue-900 transition group-hover:scale-100">
    <li class="group/open hover:bg-bluegray-medium relative mx-0.5 my-0.5 mt-0.5 rounded-xl px-1 py-0.5 text-lg font-normal leading-8 group-hover/students:visible">
      <a class="text-lg font-bold text-white" href="#">Students</a>
      <ul class="invisible absolute left-[235px] top-[-8px] w-60 rounded-xl bg-green-500 hover:visible group-hover/open:visible">
        <li class="hover:bg-bluegray-medium mx-0.5 my-0.5 mt-0.5 rounded-xl px-1 py-0.5 text-lg font-bold leading-8 hover:visible group-hover/open:visible">Active</li>
        <li class="hover:bg-bluegray-medium mx-0.5 my-0.5 mt-0.5 rounded-xl px-1 py-0.5 text-lg font-bold leading-8 hover:visible group-hover/open:visible">Pending</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="group/open hover:bg-bluegray-medium relative mx-0.5 my-0.5 mt-0.5 rounded-xl px-1 py-0.5 text-lg font-normal leading-8 group-hover/educators:visible">
      <a class="text-lg font-bold">Educators</a>
      <ul class="invisible absolute left-[235px] top-[-64px] w-60 rounded-xl bg-green-500 hover:visible group-hover/open:visible">
        <li class="hover:bg-bluegray-medium mx-0.5 my-0.5 mt-0.5 rounded-xl px-1 py-0.5 text-lg font-bold leading-8 hover:visible group-hover/open:visible">Active2</li>
        <li class="hover:bg-bluegray-medium mx-0.5 my-0.5 mt-0.5 rounded-xl px-1 py-0.5 text-lg font-bold leading-8 hover:visible group-hover/open:visible">Pending2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: It's because you have a gap between the main menu item, and the sub menu. As soon as the cursor moves into that gap, you are not hovering the main menu item any more.